# Packages are not compatible with netcoreapp2.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Today this error ocurred again. Visual Studio does not recognize most of the packages instaled in Microsoft.AspNetCore.All but I'm also getting problems with:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet

The error message is like this for every package:

> > The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.0 package is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp, Version = v2.0). The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.0 package supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard, Version = v2.0)

I got pass this issue before doing the following:

- Updating VS to version 15.3.1
- Updating SDK to version 2.0

Now, I have updated NuGet.Commandline to 4.3 but the problem persists.

I'm also getting this alert:

> > There is no way to resolve the conflict between "System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version = 4.1.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version = 4.0.1.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a ". "System.Collections.NonGeneric, Version = 4.1.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a" will be chosen arbitrarily. Application D: \ Visual Studio \ MSBuild \ 15.0 \ Bin \ Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1964

Any other update I shall look into? Any help is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

If you are using dotNET CLI, then just run this command,

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

Comment: had to run this and a dotnet restore --force

Answer (score 5):

Solved by updating Visual Studio to version 15.3.3

It seems this will be happen often until aspnetcore2.0 stabilizes itself.

Comment: It heavily relies on NuGet assemblies, so updating to latest VS binaries (containing latest NuGet assemblies) is a must. Even VS2015 has received a NuGet update this time.

Comment: Does not solve when you aren't using Visual Studio. Even happens on a fresh `dotnet new webapi` pushed straight to Azure - fails on their build too

Comment: @nathanchere For your particular case you should explore another options. This case is exposed as in Visual Studio and the answer is made to that specific case.

Comment: Sorry yeah missed the Visual Studio tag, changed to upvote accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is getting this error or a similar error when running pipelines (builds) in Azure DevOps, then there is a different fix for that. In order to fix the pipeline, we had to add a [NuGet tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) task that forced the current build to use a version of NuGet >= 5.8.

Here is a screenshot of the task:
[image]

For complete reference, here is the error message that we were getting on Azure DevOps pipeline:

> Errors in
> G:...\ProjectName.Test.csproj
> Package Moq 4.12.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2). Package Moq 4.12.0 supports:
> - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by clearing global-packages folder. Run either :

```
$ nuget locals global-packages -clear
```

or

```
$ dotnet nuget locals global-packages --clear
```